# Are there any magic items that can increase spell range?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

Certain abilities in the game allow you to increase the range of your spells such as extended spell or the [Spell Sniper](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/spell-sniper) feat. Are there any magic items that can also grant these benefits?

Answer (score 5):

### Not any that do it in a general way

While it is always hard to prove a negative, as of the time of this writing there appears to be no magic item that would allow you to extend ranges of your spells in a general way like a feat like Spell Sniper would.

*Wand of Wonder* extends (or reduces) the range of some spells it can cast to 120 feet:

> If the effect causes you to cast a spell from the wand, the spell's save DC is 15. If the spell normally has a range expressed in feet, its range becomes 120 feet if it isn't already.

Of these the range of *faerie fire* (normally 60 feet), *stinking cloud* (normally 90 feet), and *enlarge* (normally 30 feet) is increased - but you cannot select, the wand determines its effects randomly.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to house-rule it into 5e.  There was something similar to Spell Sniper in D&D 3.5, Enlarge Spell metamagic feat. It allows you to "alter a spell with a range of close, medium, or long to increase its range by 100%." (PHB 3.5, pg.94) The metamagic feats could be duplicated by the Metamagic Rods. I don't see any reason you couldn't homebrew a Spell Sniper Rod.

Here is how it worked in 3.5e for reference.
"Metamagic rods hold the essence of a metamagic feat allowing a spell to be altered.  A caster may only use one metamagic rod on any given spell. Normal metamagic rods can be used with spells of 6th level or lower. Lesser rods can be used with spells of 3rd level or lower, while greater rods can be used with spells of 9th level or lower.   Metamagic, Enlarge: The wielder can cast up to three spells per day that are enlarged as though using the Enlarge Spell feat." (DMG 3.5, pg. 236)

Comment: Hello and welcome. If you are suggesting house rules, you should back it up with references to your experience. How did you do it? How did it work? This site format don't work for guessing and opinions, and things that has no source in the rules should have one in the experience. –

Comment: +1 good find, I remember using the metamagic feats :)